# Change color of specific tick in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I created custom ticks with ggplot using:

```
library(ggplot2)

ticksX <- data.frame (t = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))
ticksY <- data.frame (t = c(0,0.25,0.3868,0.5,0.75,1))

ggplot(data=data.frame()) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(ticksY$t),limits=c(0,1), 
                            labels=expression(0,0.25,'Colour this one.'
                                              ,0.5,0.75,1)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(ticksX$t),limits=c(0,1),
                     labels=expression(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))
```

[image]

How can I colour the label above? (and only that one)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to `theme` `axis.text.y`, and pass `colour` a vector with a color for each label.

```
ggplot(data=data.frame()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(ticksY$t),limits=c(0,1), 
                     labels=expression(0,0.25,'Colour this one.',0.5,0.75,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(ticksX$t),limits=c(0,1), labels=expression(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = c('black', 'black','green', 'black', 'black', 'black')))
```

renders

[image: plot with green tick label]