# Create conditional labelling for a continuous axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-statements, axis-labels

I would like to conditionally alter the color/face/etc of a continuous tick mark label using logic instead of hard coding.  For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
xx=rpois(1000,lambda = 40)
y=density(xx,n=3600,from=0)

ggplot(data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = 0, colour = y)) + 
  scale_color_viridis() +
  labs(y='Density',x='Count',colour='Density')+
  geom_vline(xintercept=40,color='red') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,40,seq(25,100,25)),limits=c(0,100))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face=c('plain','bold',rep('plain',4)),
                                   color=ifelse(y$x==60,'red','black')))
```

So in my example above, hard coding is seen in the `face` function and that works (I can do the same thing for `color`).  It's not a big deal here since I only have a few breaks.  In future scenarios, though, I may have significantly more breaks or a less simple coloring scheme needed for my axes.  Is there a more efficient solution to create this labeling based on conditional logic?  My first attempt is seen in `color` function but that does not work .  The issue is identifying the object to use in the logical statement.  Maybe there is a behind the scenes variable I can call for the breaks (similar to using `..level..` for a density plot).  If that's the case, bonus points if you can teach me how to find it/figure that out on my own

Comment: "Behind the scenes" variables like `..level..` are generally only available inside `aes()`.

Comment: I don't think you can do it programmatically within `theme`. But if you already have specified a `breaks` vector, just use it to create also the face vector in advance. See also: [Change color of specific tick in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841470/change-color-of-specific-tick-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Thanks!  These helped out a lot.  I took your advice and defined my `breaks` vector before the plot.  I was then able to use the `ifelse` logic within theme... i.e. `ifelse(breaks==40,'red','black')`  I'm not sure it's any better than defining the color (or face) vector before the plot like the breaks vector but I thought it was interesting to see it work.

Comment: @godzilla you should write your solution as an answer and accept it to mark this question answered. It's an interesting question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick thanks to Djork for teaching me some QnA etiquette...

I was able to solve this problem by defining my break points outside of ggplot and then using `ifelse` logic within the `theme` function to create my desired outcome.  The updated (and working) example of my original code is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
xx=rpois(1000,lambda = 40)
y=density(xx,n=3600,from=0)

med_x=median(xx)
breakers = c(seq(0,100,25),med_x)

ggplot(data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = 0, colour = y)) + 
  scale_color_viridis() +
  labs(y='Density',x='Count',colour='Density')+
  geom_vline(xintercept=40,color='red') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breakers,limits=c(0,100))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face=ifelse(breakers==med_x,'bold','plain'),
                                   color=ifelse(breakers==med_x,'red','black')))
```

I haven't tried this on more complicated logic yet but I assume that this approach will work across all logical formatting.